# In ag-grid using angular2 gridOptions.api.refreshView() is not updating the grid data

Tags: angular, datagrid, ag-grid

On an Edit button click I'm **reconfiguring gridOptions** by setting the editable property of columns to true and making several other data changes. The gridOptions property is updated correctly however on calling **this.gridOptions.api.refreshView()** inside AfterContentChecked lifecycle event of Angular 2 the grid view is not getting updated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most gridOption properties are read once at grid initialization and not again.

If you want to update data you'll need to use the api (ie api.setRowData for blanket changes, or see the refresh docs ( https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/ ) for more lower level editing options.

For column editing, the editable property can be a function, which could read some other data to determine if a column/cell is editable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Updating row data through api.setRowData() solved one issue. Regarding setting the column editable property dynamically on a button click, like you had suggested I used a function which would return a boolean. Also I had incorporated other changes in my columns like column headerName changes in an object colDefs. Then I set **gridOptions.columnDefs** to colDefs as this.gridOptions.columnDefs = colDefs. This however did not update the grid view although gridOptions object was updated.

Comment: as with setRowData, for column changes you'll need to use api.setColumnDefs - most properties on gridOptions are only read once. Subsequent changes need to be made through the api. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my issue even without calling refreshView(). Just want to understand though, when do we need to use refreshView() to redraw the rows/columns.

Comment: no, if you use setRowData you wont need to call refreshView